# .htaccess rewrites - is there a leaner, tighter way to combine multiple directives

Tags: .htaccess

I want to find the leanest way to code these common rewrites: Strip 'www.', '.php', 'trailing slashes' and Force 'https'. But I've cobbled these together from various posts on S/O, and I think I don't trust my frankenstein. Is there some way tighter and leaner than this?

```
RewriteEngine on

# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Strip www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

# Force HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

# Strip php extension
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=302]

# Strip trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]
```

I tried writing loads of variations of a batch of 4 conditions and one rule, but thay all failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. So is your question is, you want to club all 4 rules sets into a single one? If yes then I don't think its possible, cheers.

Comment: Even if it were possible to combine those rules (it probably is, though complex, so error prone), it would not really make too much sense: the first two rules lead to a second request anyway. Any you need the last two rules independent from that, since a client might start requesting the final host. Further the last two rules contradict each other, so only once is going to get applied anyway. So although it might be possible to combine some logic you would have to double it to keep the separate function they provide.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, that logic really helped clarify - you're saying I shouldn't actually WANT to combine them because there's a reduced load on the server if I keep them separate, because there are fewer conditions met. Right?

Comment: No, I said nothing about the load. In my eyes you could combine the rules from a certain standpoint on an implementation level, but that would only suffice for a specific request scenario. For different request scenarios you can _not_ use a single, combined rule, you actually _need_ separate rules. Which is why I fail to see any advantage in combining them.

Comment: ok thx - logic alone defines your suggestion. And as a bonus, is the load smaller?